# can Estimote Android SDK see iPhone Estimote Virtual Beacon?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

still waiting for the beacons from Estimote to arrive. meanwhile, I cannot get the Android SDK to see the iPhone Virtual Beacon (Estimote).

Any ideas?

I am using the Github Android SDK. Should I change/keep the UUID provided there?

```
private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimote Virtual Beacon broadcasts with a UUID of `8492E75F-4FD6-469D-B132-043FE94921D8`.